# Testing validity of URL in Applescript not working

Tags: url, curl, applescript

I have this script that supposed to go to a text file line by line and if there a URL in each line it should open it in separate tabs in Safari. The part without the URL validity checking works but it doses not when I use CURL.

```
set myDelay to 0.2
set errorLog to {}
set urlText to read POSIX file "/USERS/KAMEL/transfer.txt" as «class utf8»
set urlList to paragraphs of urlText
repeat with aUrl in urlList
set aUrl to contents of aUrl
  if aUrl ≠ "" then
     try
        do shell script "curl " & aUrl
           tell application "Safari" to open location aUrl
           -- open location aUrl
           delay myDelay
          on error
          set end of errorLog to aUrl
        exit repeat
     end try
  end if
end repeat
```

Answer (score 0):

Safari has dedicated API to create new tabs.

Try this, it uses curl to return the HTTP status code

```
set urlText to read file ((path to home folder as text) & "transfer.txt") as «class utf8»
set urlList to paragraphs of urlText
set errorLog to {}
tell application "Safari" to if (count documents) is 0 then make new document
repeat with aUrl in urlList
    set theScript to "curl -o /dev/null -s -I -w '%{http_code}' " & aUrl
    try
        set theStatus to (do shell script theScript) as integer
        if theStatus < 400 then
            tell application "Safari"
                tell window 1 to make new tab with properties {URL:aUrl}
            end tell
        end if
    on error e
        set end of errorLog to (e & space & aUrl)
    end try
end repeat
```